# Install new version over existing on Windows (upgrade)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have Python 2.7.3 and considering to install new 2.7.5 version, but I can't find information if it's possible to upgrade current (and keep my modules intact) or is it advised to install as separate and reinstall all my modules one by one (which I don't want to do)?

Comment: Just install 2.7.5 and then copy all self-installed modules from 2.7.3. Alternatively just reinstall them by hand and use this opportunity to upgrade all your modules to their latest versions.

Comment: Copy where? It will try to install in `C:\Python27` where Python 2.7.3 is.

Comment: Then choose to install the 2.7.5 in, for example `C:\Python275`. Change your `PATH` and may be `PYTHONPATH` to fit with this location.

Comment: Yeah right, but just copying `site-packages` folder over to your suggested `C:\Python275` won't be enough for some modules as they require libraries from `C:\Python27\libs`, not mentioning I have no idea if some modules would like new location as absolute path is changed.

Comment: What I want to know if it's possible to install 2.7.5 over 2.7.3, being same major version,  without breaking things

Comment: Cant you select the repair method in the installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install Python2.7.5 over 2.7.3 and everything is fine. (I do that)

The folder where your libraries are installed to `site-packages` will be left untouched.

Also Python2.7.3 has the same c-Interface as Python2.7.5 so you will be able to use compiled modules as well.

I remember uninstalling Python and it deleted only the files it brought to my computer. All my programming work was left untouched.

If you really encounter issues that I do not know of, you can simply reinstall the older version.

The great thing about this is if you choose the advanced option to compile files, it will even go through your installed modules and compile them.

Comment: I installed it without even removing previous version (after reading your reply). Installer informed me that it will upgrade (overwrite) current installation. Test it with couple of scripts and everything seems fine.